# Azure AD B2C token endpoint returns scope slash

Tags: ios, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to integrate SSO authorization using Azure MSAL (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc).

But I get an error:

```
Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-50003 "(null)" UserInfo={MSALDeclinedScopesKey=(
    "{client_id}"
), MSALGrantedScopesKey=(
    "/"
), MSALErrorDescriptionKey=Server returned less scopes than requested, MSALInvalidResultKey=<MSALResult: 0x600000fc6340>}
```

I review the request to `token` endpoint and it looks like:[image]

So i seen `"scope": "/"` and it looks like there's a mistake here.

Im using `Identity Experience Framework` with custom policies. I'm looking now for how to change the response from the server to the scope field.

Is it possible to do it somehow?

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same problem when using MSAL to authenticate for OneDrive. Did you get any further with this?